# Create a new column in a view and assign it a data type

Tags: sql-server-2008

here is my query:

```
CREATE VIEW VIEW2
AS SELECT [Column1],
(NULL) AS column2 VARCHAR(10)
FROM VIEW1;
```

I get an error in the third line.

If I leave the query like this, without specifying the data type for Column2, the query works, but the default data type will be int, whereas I want to have VARCHAR.

```
CREATE VIEW VIEW2
AS SELECT [Column1],
(NULL) AS column2 
FROM VIEW1;
```

Can you please help? Thank you!

Note: Only Column1 is in VIEW1. Column2 is NOT in VIEW1, it's a generated column with NULL values.

Comment: You do know that views calling views is generally a very poor techinique and can cause performance issues? You really don't want to go down that path because it's anightmare to fix later  when you have a lot of records and the performance issues show up. And I am at a loss as to why you would want to do this. If the column isn't in a table and it can only be NULL, what good is it doing you? You can't update it with any other values

Answer (score 10):

You'll want this.

```
CREATE VIEW VIEW2
AS SELECT [Column1],
cast(NULL as varchar(10)) AS column2
FROM VIEW1;
```